# Declarative security on methods in .NET 3.5 - how do I lock down a method's permissions?

Tags: .net, security, permissions, declarative-security

I'm using .NET 3.5. Say I have a method that accesses a specific file, and a specific registry key.
I want to add declarative security definitions that restrict the method so that it can only access the file and the registry key specified, and nothing else.

When I try:

```
    [RegistryPermission(SecurityAction.PermitOnly, Read = "registry key path"]
    [FileIOPermission(SecurityAction.PermitOnly, Read = "file path")]
```

... it lets me read the file path, but not the registry key - I get a security exception.

If I use:

```
    [RegistryPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Read = "registry key path"]
    [FileIOPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Read = "file path")]
```

... it lets me read the file and the registry key, but also lets me access other files.

Am I missing something about how these methods should be used to acheive this effect?

**Edit:**

The code I am using to access the registry key is:

```
    RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine;
    rk = rk.OpenSubKey("MyKey");
    string registryVal = rk.GetValue("Test").ToString();
```

and therefore the permission declaration is:

```
[RegistryPermission(SecurityAction.PermitOnly, Read = @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\MyKey")]
```

Thanks.

Comment: If your application / AppDomain runs in full trust, those attributes will do nothing. Are you running in partial trust?

Comment: Well it definitely fails if I try to access a file that isn't listed in the attributes when using PermitOnly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what `SecurityAction.Demand` does is throw a security exception if your current call-chain *doesn't already have* the specified access.  It doesn't change the access that you have (so it wouldn't restrict which other files you can write to), but you should see a security exception if you don't have access to your specified path.

From what you specify, `PermitOnly` would be the correct value to use (it restricts access to only the item you specify), and so I wonder whether your registry key code is where the problem is.  One typical example is that the .NET registry classes can be used to open a key as either "read only" or "read-write" - and if you try to open read-write, you'll get a security exception even if you never try to change the value.

Can you post the code to your registry access?

Comment: Edited my question to include registry access code, thanks :)

Comment: Which line does it crash on?  The `OpenSubKey` or the `GetValue`?

Comment: OpenSubKey. Hmm, maybe it also needs explicit permissions for Registry.LocalMachine

Comment: That was it. I had to add [RegistryPermission(SecurityAction.PermitOnly, Read = @"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE")] as well. Thanks for your help.